# What is swift equivalent of android ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getFloat()?

Tags: android, ios, swift

I am working on a project where I have to read data from device and then convert it in byte array and then read some bytes(4 byte) and convert them in float and use it. I have code that is working fine but in android but I am unable to convert the code correctly. Here is the android code

```
try {
          byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(mScanRecord, 5, 9); //mScanRecord is byte array (byte[]) containing 11 byte
          searchModel.setData("" + ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getFloat());
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          searchModel.setData("" + 0);
    }
```

And here is the code that I converted in swift

```
typealias Byte = UInt8

func fromByteArray<T>(_ value: [UInt8], _: T.Type) -> T {
    return value.withUnsafeBytes {
        $0.baseAddress!.load(as: T.self)
    }
}

func getUnitValue(byteArray:[UInt8]) -> Float {
    let value = fromByteArray([byteArray[7], byteArray[8], byteArray[9], byteArray[10]], Float.self)

    return value
}

..... In Some function I call .....
searchModel.setData(data: String(format: "%.10f", getUnitValue(byteArray: byteArray)))
```

It is giving me value but value is very different from android

**Edit**
I am expecting value around 
2.0405695(like in android)

2.0405587

2.0526589

but I am getting

547669365842.0000

-652321236542.0000

0.000000103

value changes every few seconds in both device

In iOS

```
Printing description of byteArray:
▿ 13 elements
  - 0 : 195
  - 1 : 4
  - 2 : 1
  - 3 : 213
  - 4 : 130
  - 5 : 0
  - 6 : 0
  - 7 : 64
  - 8 : 2
  - 9 : 152
  - 10 : 178
  - 11 : 213
  - 12 : 130
```

In Android

[image]

Values looks different but these are same if convert them to decimal to hex

Comment: What does the byte array contain? What result do you get and what do you expect? – Also your Java code copies bytes 5..8 and the Swift copies the bytes 7...10 from the array.

Comment: @MartinR I updated question for expected values, Java code copies 5, 6, 7, 8 and Swift copies 7, 8, 9, 10 because byte array length in java is 11 byte and in ios it's 13 byte, I am getting 2 more byte then in android in the beginning so I have to pick value from 7

Comment: What does the byte array contain??

Comment: @MartinR updeted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte array contains the *big endian* representation of a 32-bit
floating point value. You have to convert that to the host byte order
(which is little-endian on all current Apple platforms):

```
func getUnitValue(byteArray:[UInt8]) -> Float {
    let value = fromByteArray([byteArray[7], byteArray[8], byteArray[9], byteArray[10]], UInt32.self)
    return Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bigEndian: value))
}

let array: [UInt8] = [195, 4, 1, 213, 130, 0, 0, 64, 2, 152, 178, 213, 130]

print(getUnitValue(byteArray: array)) // 2.0405587
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case float number was in little endian and I changed this line:

```
return Float(bitPattern: UInt32(littleEndian: value))
```